# sqlalchemy association_proxy pagination

Tags: python-2.7, pagination, sqlalchemy

I have the data model below.  How would I paginate comments order by by date descending

```
user.comments.order_by(Comment.date.desc())[0:100];
```

Is all I can come up with, but association_proxy does not have a order_by? What I'm trying to do is return a list of comments by the user and order them by the most recent comment.  I have a lot of areas in my code that will use a similar pattern.

Example of my data model:

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String, ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship, backref

from sqlalchemy.ext.associationproxy import association_proxy
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

Base = declarative_base()

class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'user'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(64))

    # association proxy of "user_comments" collection
    # to "comment" attribute
    comments = association_proxy('user_comments', 'comment')

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

class UserComment(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'user_comment'
    user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('user.id'), primary_key=True)
    comment_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('comment.id'), primary_key=True)

    # bidirectional attribute/collection of "user"/"user_comments"
    user = relationship(User,
                backref=backref("user_comments",
                                cascade="all, delete-orphan")
            )

    # reference to the "Comment" object
    comment = relationship("Comment")

    def __init__(self, comment=None, user=None):
        self.user = user
        self.comment = comment

class Comment(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'comment'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    comment = Column('comment', String(64))
    date = db.Column(db.DateTime)

    def __init__(self, comment):
        self.comment = comment

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'Comment(%s)' % repr(self.comment)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In SQLAlchemy, relationship-bound attributes in general don't have an "order_by()" method as you describe.   In SQLAlchemy "order_by()" is a method of things that produce SELECT statements like session.query() and select().  The one case where something like "user.comments.order_by()" would make any sense is if you're using a so-called "dynamic" relationship, which is a special strategy where the collection attached to an instance is actually a Query() object.   Above, I don't see any use of "dynamic" so that doesn't apply.

In your above example, if you already had a "user" object loaded, and you said "user.comments", at best that would load the comments just once and then they're held in memory.  So you'd need an ORDER BY on the relationship here, but you're using the association object pattern which makes it much more difficult to do this.  I don't above see the need for you to use the association object pattern as you don't have any additional attributes on it so if that's the case I'd just lose the association mapping and put order_by on the relationship, that is, replace the UserComment class as below:

```
class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'user'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(64))

    comments = relationship("Comment",
                        secondary=Table('user_comment', Base.metadata,
                            Column('user_id', ForeignKey('user.id'), primary_key=True),
                            Column('comment_id', ForeignKey('comment.id'), primary_key=True)
                        ),
                        order_by="Comment.date.desc()"
                )

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
```

Now if you really have a reason to have UserComment mapped explicitly, you can still get the effect you want if you make a relationship that skips the UserComment mapping, and if you put "dynamic" on it the exact syntax you want will work:

```
from sqlalchemy import *
from sqlalchemy.orm import *

from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

Base = declarative_base()

class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'user'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(64))

    comments = relationship("Comment",
                        secondary="user_comment",
                        lazy="dynamic", viewonly=True)

    def __init__(self, name, **kw):
        super(User, self).__init__(**kw)
        self.name = name

class UserComment(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'user_comment'
    user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('user.id'), primary_key=True)
    comment_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('comment.id'), primary_key=True)

    user = relationship(User,
                backref=backref("user_comments",
                                cascade="all, delete-orphan")
            )

    comment = relationship("Comment")

    def __init__(self, comment=None, user=None):
        self.user = user
        self.comment = comment

class Comment(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'comment'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    comment = Column('comment', String(64))
    date = Column(DateTime)

    def __init__(self, comment):
        self.comment = comment

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'Comment(%s)' % repr(self.comment)

e = create_engine("sqlite://", echo=True)
Base.metadata.create_all(e)

s = Session(e)

s.add_all([
    User(name='u1', user_comments=[
        UserComment(comment=Comment(comment='c1')),
        UserComment(comment=Comment(comment='c2')),
        UserComment(comment=Comment(comment='c3')),
    ])
])
s.commit()

u1 = s.query(User).first()
print u1.comments.order_by(Comment.date.desc()).all()
```

(side note, why User->Comments is many to many at all?   Can a Comment be owned by more than one User?  That seems strange? )